# How to get which element was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple **div** in my **html** as follows:

```
<div id="myDiv">
....

</div>
```

Also I have set the **onlick** event on the `window.click` as follows:

```
window.onclick = function()
{
    // do something
 }
```

So if I click, anywhere in the **div**, how can I find that this click was made inside **"myDiv"**

**Note : I cannot add the click event on my div, it is generated randomly from jqgrid**

Comment: Why not attach a click handler directly to the `#myDiv` element?

Comment: event.target ... does that help?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thanks for your comment. I have added a note to my question, kindly check :-)

Comment: In that case you could use a delegated event handler on the div: `$('#container').on('click', '#myDiv', function() {});`

Comment: As you have tagged this as jQuery, @ory McCrossan's solution is the correct one. For dynamically added content use a delegated event handler attached to a non-changing ancestor element (`document` being the safest default). The answer by @erkaner is closest to the best solution (just needs a tweak based on the comment below it). Using the one-and-only`onclick` property of window is also a bad idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aim of the question is simply this. "I wish to know when a dynamically added div is clicked". The moment you see *dynamically added* think delegated events! :)

As this question allows for jQuery, [the answer by `@erkaner`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627660/how-to-get-which-element-was-clicked/29627767#29627767) is close to ideal for this situation. I just wish to explain why it is the *appropriate solution*.

```
$(document).on("click","#myDiv", function (event) {
     // Do something
});
```

**Explanation:**

- This uses a jQuery *delegated event handler*. The event handling is "delegated" to a non-changing ancestor of the intended target, hence the name.
- The chosen ancestor is `document` in this case.
- You should use the closest non-changing ancestor to the target, but `document` is the best default if nothing else is closer/convenient.
- Warning: Do not use `body` for delegated events as it has a bug (styling can cause it to not get bubbled mouse events).
- The event (`click` in this case) bubbles up to the handler element (i.e. document).
- The jQuery selector (in this case `#myDiv`) is then applied to *just the elements in the bubble-chain*. This is very efficient.
- The supplied handler function is then just applied to any matching elements *that caused the event*.

The upshot of all this is that the element *need not exist until event time* (it does not need to exist when *the event was registered*).

Further, because delegation is typically used on *mouse events* (and not 50,000 times a second) any speed difference between this and a "raw" event handler is negligible. The benefits far outweigh any trivial speed difference.

**Regarding the other `onclick=` answers**

- Firstly, using the single `window.onclick` property is a bad idea as you stop anything else using it (not that anyone using jQuery should use it).
- Secondly the event parameter passed to `onclick` is not provided by all browsers (this should be enough to stop anyone using it). There are workarounds, but jQuery was created to avoid browser workarounds :)

**Notes:**

If the naming is not under your control, you just need something to match on. Worst case, it could be as simple as "match any div under any table", but that will depend on your specific HTML & code:

```
$(document).on("click","table div", function (event) {
     // Do something
});
```

Here is a practical example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/eyo5Lnsy/

Comment: @Sashi Kant: Glad it helps. It is very important to understand how jQuery delegated events work as they are a great solution to many problems (if used properly) :)

Comment: And one last question, what if I want to do something, onclick of anywhere in the page except `myDiv`

Comment: @Sashi Kant: I will add an example as that one is a tiny bit complicated :)

Comment: @Sashi Kant: This can be shortened (chain the handlers), but should help: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/eyo5Lnsy/1/ Remove the `stopPropagation` to see what happens without them! :)

Comment: Actually `event.stopPropagation()` stops the onclick event of `myDiv` which is different than that what we have on the rest of the document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75285/discussion-between-sashi-kant-and-trueblueaussie).

Comment: When I click on a row present in `#grid0`, if I click on it, the code within   `$(document).on("click",':not("#grid0")', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('logger 1 :'+jQuery('#grid0, #ui-datepicker-div').find(event.target).length);
   refreshMyDyna();
   outerLastSel=-1;  
  
 
 }); ` is executed

Comment: @Sashi Kant: You must *also* have a handler on `#grid0` for that technique to work. Please ask a new question as the comments are not good enough :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).on("click","#myDiv", function (event) {
     alert(event.target.id);
});
```

Comment: `alert(this.id);` is a little shorter.

Comment: As this was a jQuery question, this would be the most appropriate answer so +1. You should explain how delegated events work though, to avoid this answer being discounted. Also mention the appropriate choice of target for the delegated handler (closest non-changing ancestor of the dynamic element, document being the default).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks for your response, but I have an issue here, where `myDiv` is generated from javascript from multiple points(`mydiv` name was an example). So in that case, I dont think this code will work, after this line is executed and then the div is created.

Comment: @Sashi Kant: Incorrect. I am adding a more detailed answer explaining this answer in full. Hang on a few minutes.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: That will be very nice of you :)

Comment: @Sashi Kant: Explanation added as promised. If you can provide your actual HTML I will be able to change it to match any need you could possibly have. Delegated event handler are wonderful when used properly  :)

Answer (score 4):

Get the event from the function: `window.onclick = function(event)` then inside the function you can use it as `event.target`:

```
window.onclick = function(event)
{
    alert(event.target);
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, event isn't always passed as a parameter by all browsers. event.target also doesn't exist in older IE versions. To ensure it works in older browsers you can add: "event = event || window.event;" and "event.target = event.target || event.srcElement;"

Comment: It is also a bad idea to sequester the one and only `window.onclick` property to do this. An appropriate jQuery solution (as tagged) would be a delegated event handler (see @erkaner's answer).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - without using jQuery

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    // this div has been clicked
    console.log('this div has been clicked');
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the non-jQuery solution for dynamically created elements

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if( e.target.id == 'myDiv' )
    {
        // this div has been clicked
        console.log('this div has been clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's good to see `.addEventListener()` instead of this `.onclick`

Comment: @Regent - thanks, i also felt it was missing a certain "vanilla-ness"

Comment: If you dig around all the comments, and the question update, the OP's `myDiv` is actually added *dynamically* so this will not work. Sorry.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I did not see the question was talking about dynamically created content, I've updated my answer to reflect that now - thanks

Comment: No problem. That happened later.  DV removed :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

myDiv.style.cursor = 'pointer';
myDiv.onclick = function() {
    //DO SOMETHING
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go.

```
$('body').click(function(e) {      
  if (e.target.id == 'myDiv') {
    alert('My Div!!!!');
  }
});​
```

Comment: why not use #myDiv as selector for the click instead?

Comment: @Mackan it's dark magic. About this code: `if  (e.target.id == 'myDiv')` is shorter and works faster.

Comment: @Mackan The OP wanted to determine if the element was the one clicked on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Is this compatible for all the browsers?
What if any element which is a deep child of `myDiv`, will the if condition return true?

Comment: @Sashi Kant Yes, it will return true for any element that is a child of the <body> tag. I tested this on Chrome, Firefox and IE11. No one can make me use an earlier version, sorry. But since this is JQuery 1.11.2 it should work from IE8. Also note my edit to the answer, Regent's comment made sense so I made that change. Thanks Regent.

Comment: Yes saw that :) Hope there would be an option to accept multiple answers :) Thanks once again

Comment: Please note: Bubbled mouse events can fail with `body` due to styling. Best to use `document` as the default (as you would with delegated events) :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "body" ).click(function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( "clicked: " + event.target.nodeName );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
....

</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check below code. check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g6t75ge3/)

use [event.target](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp) to get clicked element .

```
window.onclick = function(event)
{
  if(event.target.id == "myDiv"){
    alert("here")
  }else{
    alert('Body')
  }
 console.log(event.target.id)
}
```

Comment: Perfect? Perhaps not: 1) `event` isn't always passed as a parameter by all browsers. 2) You are sequestering the one and only `window.onclick` property so nothing else can use it. 3) This was a jQuery question, so the most appropriate solution, avoiding all these issues, is a delegated event handler so 4) Your solution is not perfect, it is fragile.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie read question again it also taged in javascript . and  and  `myDiv ` is not fixed id so `erkaner ` answer will not work . i provide example as per his question here no need  `event delegated ` .

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie check note in question `Note : I cannot add the click event on my div, it is generated randomly from jqgrid

`

Comment: And if you knew jQuery you would know that is what *delegated event handlers* are for... it "delegates" event handling to a non-changing ancestor element (the element does not need to exist until *event time*) :) Please ensure you understand the issues raised before arguing them.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie on click want to check which element was clicked not want to attach `onclick` event to specific element

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  i know `jQuery delegated event ` . dose erkaner answer fire when i click ane ware in window ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1fhrr7ug/  .. dose this alert when i click anywhere in window ?  check question he want to know which element click when click event fire anywhere in window not on fixed element

Comment: No... the question says he wants to do something with the div1 is clicked. "So if I click, anywhere *in the div*". The example code he used has mislead you into thinking it does more.

Comment: can you explain this note in question? `Note : I cannot add the click event on my div, it is generated randomly from jqgrid`

Comment: The `div` he wishes to click on is created dynamically by jqgrid so he cannot use a statically connected jQuery select like `$('#div1').click(...)` to add a handler. I am adding a detailed explanation to a new answer with full credit to @erkaner. Wait for that.

Comment: I have added a new answer, purely to explain this matter in full as delegated events can appear obscure. The OP has also asked this be explained further. Sorry for the DV, but I must stand by that. This is not an "appropriate solution" to the problem (as I understand it). If the problem is changed and this becomes more suitable I will remove my DV. Thanks.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie here misunderstanding in question but why my answer will not work .. you will get which element is clicked ?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  this will alos work its not a totally wrong answer. and thanks for clear misunderstanding :)

Comment: "Work" is a relative term here. To repeat: 1) `event` isn't always passed as a parameter by all browsers. 2) You are sequestering the one and only `window.onclick` property so nothing else can use it. For these two reason (already stated before) this is why this is not a "good" solution. It will not "work" on all browsers or with all other code (anything that used `window.onclick` will break).